# how to find out the scaling factors to match two curves in matlab?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have two data sets obtained at different days. The results I got from two different data sets have similar shape but different values (see fig1). I am trying to match the second data set (x2,y2) to the first one (x1,y1) by multiply a constant **A** in x and **B** in y of the second data (see fig2).[image: Figure 1] 
[image: Figure 2]

for example:

data1:

x1=[-0.3:0.06:2.1]';

y1=[ 0.001
0.001
0.004
0.014
0.052
0.166
0.330
0.416
0.340
0.247
0.194
0.197
0.237
0.330
0.428
0.542
0.669
0.767
0.855
0.900
0.913
0.904
0.873
0.811
0.765
0.694
0.631
0.585
0.514
0.449
0.398
0.351
0.309
0.273
0.233
0.211
0.182
0.154
0.137
0.117
0.101
]';

data2

x2=[-0.3:0.06:2.1]';

y2=[0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.025
0.230
0.447
0.425
0.269
0.194
0.225
0.326
0.477
0.636
0.791
0.931
1.036
1.104
1.117
1.123
1.062
0.980
0.897
0.780
0.675
0.571
0.471
0.390
0.309
0.258
0.209
0.161
0.129
0.099
0.079
0.063
0.047
0.038
0.027
0.023
0.015
]';

To find out the scaling factor **A** & **B**, I am thinking about obtaining **B** by minimizing the delta y between data1 and x modified data2. However I do have a good way to find out the A. How should I find out the **A** & **B** to match this two curve? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the optimization toolbox (or access to any unconstrained non-linear minimization routine), you can do the following:

Define a function that computes the error between your two curves

```
function err = sqrError(coeffs, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    % Interpolation of 'y2' with scaled 'x2' into the domain 'x1' 
    y2sampledInx1 = interp1(coeffs(1)*x2,y2,x1);
    % Squred error calculation
    err = sum((coeffs(2)*y2sampledInx1-y1).^2);
end
```

Use `fminunc` (or whatever optimizer you have available) to compute your coeffiecients:

```
coeffs = fminunc(@(c) sqrError(c,x1, y1, x2, y2),[1;1]);

A = coeffs(1);
B = coeffs(2);
plot(x1, y1, A*x2, B*y2)
```

Comment: @ jonnat: this works fine for the data set i post. but i have one question, when you use fminunuc, how do you determine the minimum range ([1,1])? when I test with my other data set,  it showed an error message as "??? Error using ==> roots at 28, Input to ROOTS must not contain NaN or Inf." do you know what maybe the cause of this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This error means that an operation in your code generated an NaN or Inf rather than a finite number. There are many reasons why this may be, including an unbounded objective function to `fminunc` or simple errors such as divisions by 0. If you want to add bounds to your coefficients, use `fmincon` instead of `fminunc`. If you want to know exactly where the NaN or Inf was generated, use `dbstop if naninf` in the beginning of your code. If you still can't find the issue, open a new question. Finally, if my answer worked for your example, please accept it so that other people know it works.

Answer (score 0):

To determine **A** you want to do a cross-correlation but instead of testing a range of time-lags, you'll want to test a range of x multipliers, i.e. **A** values.

Assuming you have a range of A values you want to test, do a correlation between the two curves (x1, y1) and (A*x2, B*y2) by multiplying the points in each curve that correspond to the same x values and sum these products. This will give you one number representing the correlation at the particular **A** value.

Repeat the above for each potential **A** value. The one that gives the maximum correlation result is the **A** value that best matches the two curves in the x dimension.

This method requires that the **A** values that you test give new x values that synchronize with the original x values so that both curves have values at the same x values.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. Can you give me some guidance to how I can synchronize the new x value with original ones?

Comment: @Tai-Yen Chen: Good question. You could avoid worrying about synchronizing the x values altogether by using any **A** values you like and then interpolating the resulting (A*x2, B*y2) data to the x1 values solely for the purpose of calculating the correlation. The interpolation would reduce the local maxima but at fine enough x resolution this wouldn't greatly affect the correlation result.

Comment: @ b3: I just test with jonnats post and it seems work. but in the routine, it does not calculate the correlation coefficient. Just curious do you have any comment on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Tai-Yen Chen - jonnat's solution uses FMINCON to minimize the difference (i.e. square error) between two curves. This, like my correlation suggestion, is a method to quantify the sameness of two curves for the purpose of judging which parameter values (i.e. A and B) provide the best results.