# Horizontal and vertical shift factors between data plots Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to implement shifting in x directions in Matlab to match two data plots. 
Let

```
data1:

x1=[-0.3:0.06:2.1]';

y1=[ 0.001 0.001 0.004 0.014 0.052 0.166 0.330 0.416 0.340 0.247 0.194 0.197 0.237 0.330 0.428 0.542 0.669 0.767 0.855 0.900 0.913 0.904 0.873 0.811 0.765 0.694 0.631 0.585 0.514 0.449 0.398 0.351 0.309 0.273 0.233 0.211 0.182 0.154 0.137 0.117 0.101 ]';

data2:

x2=[-0.3:0.06:2.1]';

y2=[0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.025 0.230 0.447 0.425 0.269 0.194 0.225 0.326 0.477 0.636 0.791 0.931 1.036 1.104 1.117 1.123 1.062 0.980 0.897 0.780 0.675 0.571 0.471 0.390 0.309 0.258 0.209 0.161 0.129 0.099 0.079 0.063 0.047 0.038 0.027 0.023 0.015 ]';
```

and so on... Xshift between the two curves shown in below figure. [see figure 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119316/how-to-find-out-the-scaling-factors-to-match-two-curves-in-matlab).

I need to shift the green curve to match with the blue curve. Hence, I looked at [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119316/how-to-find-out-the-scaling-factors-to-match-two-curves-in-matlab) and tried to implement similarly as follows. However, I modified the multiplications as additions.

```
function err = sqrError(coeffs, x1, y1, x2, y2)
% Interpolation of 'y2' with scaled 'x2' into the domain 'x1' 
y2sampledInx1 = interp1(coeffs(1)+x2,y2,x1);
% Squred error calculation
err = sum((coeffs(2)+y2sampledInx1-y1).^2);
end


coeffs = fminunc(@(c) sqrError(c,x1, y1, x2, y2),[1;1]);
A = coeffs(1);
B = coeffs(2);
plot(x1, y1, A*x2, B*y2)
```

However, I am facing the error as follows:

```
Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm;
using line-search algorithm instead. 
 > In fminunc at 383

Error using fminusub 
Objective function is undefined at initial point. Fminunc cannot continue.
```

Appreciate your inputs to correction. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error says, your objective (i.e. `sqrError`) function is undefined at initial point (i.e. `coeffs = [1;1]`).
This is because `x1` (your interpolated grid) has values outside of the range of `coeffs(1)+x2`. So basically you are trying to extrapolate rather than interpolate. In this case `interp1` returns `NaN`s in the points outside `coeffs(1)+x2`.
If you would like it to perform also extrapolation, you should use the argument `extrap`:

```
y2sampledInx1 = interp1(coeffs(1)+x2,y2,x1,method,'extrap');
```

where `method` is the interpolation method such as linear (default), spline, etc.

Comment: But here is the output:



Undefined function or variable 'method'.

Error in sqrError (line 9)
    y2sampledInx1 = interp1(coeffs(1)+x2,y2,x1,method,'extrap');

Error in @(c)sqrError(c,x1,y1,x2,y2)


Error in fminunc (line 254)
        f = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in ruf1 (line 36)
coeffs = fminunc(@(c) sqrError(c, x1, y1, x2, y2),[+0.5; 15]);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINUNC cannot continue.

Comment: Replace method with 'spline' or 'linear'. Also, it doesn't hurt to read the doc

Comment: The aim of the study is to replecate the procedure given in the following reference: Figure 4 in http://www.eng.uc.edu/~beaucag/Classes/Characterization/DMA%20Lab/IF1.1%20Fukushima.pdf

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I am able to run the code with following commands:

y2sampledInx1 = @(c) interp1(c(1)+x2,y2,x1,'cubic', 'extrap');
err = @(c) sum((c(2)+y2sampledInx1(c)-y1).^2);
opts = optimoptions('fminunc', 'TolFun',1e-16, 'TolX',1e-16,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
x0=[1.5; 1.5];
coeffs = fminunc(err,x0,opts);

However, the solution is strongly depending on the initial guess x0. If I give close x0 it is able to give good solutions. 

Hence the probelm comes here to automate this shifting process from a large data set. Your inputs are welcome. Thanks